# terminal autocomplete for ls doesn't go into the directory

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

When I attempt to tab-autocomplete an `ls` directory name, the autocomplete does not give the slash that allows me to type the next subdirectory. Instead, it gives me a space, making me have to backspace and add a slash before proceeding. e.g., If I'm at the root of a directory with the structure `dir1/dir2/dir3/test.txt`, and I type `ls di [tab]`, I get `ls dir1`  when I want `ls dir1/`.

For some other commands I use with autocomplete, this does not occur, such as `cd`. However, it also does occur with others. e.g., I use a visualization program called VMD, and when I want to run a script with VMD I would type `vmd -e dir/scriptname.tcl`. If I tried to autocomplete the directory leading to the script, the same issue occurs as with `ls`.

I have the bash-completion package properly installed. When I type `complete -p | grep " ls"`, I get `complete -F _longopt ls`

If I type `complete -d ls`, then autocomplete works correctly for the rest of the session. It's bizarre to me that I'd need to add that to my `.bashrc` file though. This issue is only coming up for me on one particular Ubuntu workstation of mine and is not present on other ones. Any ideas what might be causing this?

FYI, my `.bashrc` file already contains:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Nothing else in my `.bashrc` file related to autocompletion.

Comment: What happens if you type in `ls ` and try to double tap for auto completion is everything listed as a file or does it recognize your dir's with a `/` at the end?

Comment: When I type `ls [tab]`, everything is listed without a `/` at the end (presumably as a file).
If I do `complete -d ls` and then `ls [tab]`, only directories get listed, and with the `/` at the end.

Comment: And of course you're right that that is the root of the problem. On my other workstation, I get the same result from `complete -p | grep " ls"`, but `ls [tab]` shows the directories with slashes at the end. So why is my computer not recognizing the directories as directories?

Comment: Well, just try copying the files `/etc/bash_completion` and `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` from the ones which work to the one that is not working.

Comment: They were the same, but I found that in /etc/bash_completion.d, there was an extra file in the one that wasn't working called "isaacs", which got put there when I installed the program  from http://isaacs.sourceforge.net/index.html. Of course, removing it fixed everything.

Thanks Ziazis! If you want to put that answer, I can mark it as correct to give you the points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to crosscheck the broken files with some that work.

Necessary files/dirs would be:

`/etc/bash_completion`, `/usr/share/bash-completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d`

Once you've found the culprit adjust the files/remove unnecessary files to fix it.